# Total to Match Listbox Selections

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I have a list box on a form that a user manually selects rows containing individual quantities that need to add up to a total quantity entered on the form before selecting these records. Then the selected rows are sent to a table for print out so that the physical inventory can be updated correctly.

**I am not sure how to subtract a partial quantity when the total selected is above the specified quanitity and have the difference sent to my table.**  I have included what I have setup so far...

```
Private Sub ctrSend_Click()
Dim intI As Integer
Dim lst As ListBox
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim qtySum As Variant
Dim qtyDiff As Variant
Dim rowMax As Variant
Dim rowUpdate As Variant

Set lst = Me![lstShipping]
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ShipInv", dbOpenTable)

With lst
    If .ItemsSelected.count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
            qtySum = qtySum + .Column(3, varItem)
        Next

    If Me.[ctrQtyProd] = qtySum Then
        MsgBox "Qty Selected EQUALS Qty Being Shipped.", vbOKOnly, "Quantity Confirmation"
    ElseIf Me.[ctrQtyProd] > qtySum Then
        MsgBox "Qty Selected LESS THAN Qty Being Shipped, please select more Inventory.", vbOKOnly, "Inventory Confirmation"
    Else Me.[ctrQtyProd] < qtySum Then
        qtyDiff = qtySum - Me.[ctrQtyProd]
        .Column(3, .ItemSelected.count - 1) = .Column(3, .ItemSelected.count - 1) - qtyDiff

    End If
End With

With lst
    For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
        rst.AddNew
        rst!Order = Me.[ctrSOrder]
        rst!EntDate = Date
        rst!ShipDate = Me.[ctrSDate]
        rst!BIN = .Column(0, varItem)
        rst!SKU = .Column(1, varItem)
        rst!Lot = .Column(2, varItem)
        rst!QtyProd = .Column(3, varItem)
        rst.Update
    Next
End With
rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing
MsgBox "Warehouse Inventory Updated", vbOKOnly, "Update Confirmation"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you expand your question with a small example? Am I correct in rephrasing your goal as follows : **if the qtySum > ctrQtyProd then substract the difference from the last selected quantity in the list** ? So if I select in your list quantities `2,3 and 5` and shipping quantity=`8` then in your table you want to see quantities `2, 3 and 3`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, but I got it all solved last night. Now I am having an issue with a DAO object not wanting to find and update a record in a specific table.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I figured out to get it to do what I wanted it to do...

```
Private Sub ctrSend_Click()
Dim intI As Integer
Dim lst As ListBox
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim qtySum As Variant
Dim qtyDiff As Variant
Dim rowMax As Variant
Dim rowUpdate As Variant
Dim rowBIN As Variant
Dim sqlShip As String

Set lst = Me![lstShipping]
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ShipInv", dbOpenTable)
Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Storage", dbOpenTable)
qtySum = 0
rowMax = 0

With lst
    If .ItemsSelected.count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
            qtySum = qtySum + .Column(3, varItem)
        Next

    If Me.[ctrQtyProd] = qtySum Then
        MsgBox "Qty Selected EQUALS Qty Being Shipped.", vbOKOnly, "Confirmation Message"
    ElseIf Me.[ctrQtyProd] > qtySum Then
        MsgBox "Qty Selected LESS THAN Qty Being Shipped, please select more Inventory.", vbOKOnly, "Confirmation Message"
    Else
        qtyDiff = qtySum - Me.[ctrQtyProd]
        rowMax = lst.Column(3, lst.ItemsSelected.count)
        rowUpdate = rowMax - qtyDiff

        MsgBox "Qty Successfully Updated.", vbOKOnly, "Confirmation Message"
    End If
End With

With lst
    For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
        rst.AddNew
        rst!Order = Me.[ctrSOrder]
        rst!EntDate = Date
        rst!ShipDate = Me.[ctrSDate]
        rst!BIN = .Column(0, varItem)
        rst!SKU = .Column(1, varItem)
        rst!Lot = .Column(2, varItem)
        rst!QtyProd = rowUpdate
        rst.Update
    Next
End With
rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```